# Timer in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, timer

currently i'm trying to make a timer that require start, resume/pause, and stop method in Visual Basic. But when i adding stop method the timer did stop but not reset the value of timer. And sometimes when i try to start it again, the timer ticking to a minus value (ex: -15:-44:-12). Can you please help me? Any help and suggestions would greatly helping.

This is the code that i've been working lately

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim StartTime As DateTime 'old current time
    Dim PauseTime As DateTime 'keep track of the time when the timer is paused
    Dim TotalTimePaused As TimeSpan 'The total amount of time paused

    Private Sub BtnStart1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnStart1.Click
        BtnStart1.Enabled = False
        BtnPause1.Enabled = True
        StartTime = DateTime.Now()
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        'Subtract the current "Now" time from the start time
        'and then subtract the total time paused
        Dim ElapsedTime As TimeSpan = DateAndTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime).Subtract(TotalTimePaused)
        Label2.Text = ElapsedTime.Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) + ":" + ElapsedTime.Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) + ":" + ElapsedTime.Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
        'And if you wanted the total elapsed time from time of start then
        'subtract the current "Now" time from the start time only.
    End Sub
    Private Sub BtnPause1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnPause1.Click
        If Timer1.Enabled = False Then
            BtnPause1.Text = "Pause"
            'Add to the total time paused; the current time minus the 
            'time of pause.  this will be the total amount of time
            'paused so you can subtract it from the total amount of
            'time since the start button was pressed
            TotalTimePaused = TotalTimePaused.Add(DateAndTime.Now.Subtract(PauseTime))
            Timer1.Enabled = True
        Else
            BtnPause1.Text = "Resume"
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            'Set the pause time so it can be
            'calculated to the total time paused.
            'when the timer is resumed
            PauseTime = DateAndTime.Now
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnStop1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnStop1.Click
        If Timer1.Enabled = False Then
            BtnStart1.Enabled = True
            BtnPause1.Text = "Pause"
            TotalTimePaused = TotalTimePaused.Add(DateAndTime.Now.Subtract(PauseTime))
        Else
            Timer1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the `Stopwatch` class?

Answer (score 0):

You have this function

```
Private Sub BtnStop1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnStop1.Click
    If Timer1.Enabled = False Then
        BtnStart1.Enabled = True
        BtnPause1.Text = "Pause"
        TotalTimePaused = TotalTimePaused.Add(DateAndTime.Now.Subtract(PauseTime))
    Else
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

where you stop the timer, I think you should change this...

```
Private Sub BtnStop1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnStop1.Click
    If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
       Timer1.Enabled= False 'Here you stop the timer and 
                             'when you clic the start button this starts on
                             'on your time.
        BtnStart1.Enabled = True
        BtnPause1.Text = "Pause"
        TotalTimePaused = TotalTimePaused.Add(DateAndTime.Now.Subtract(PauseTime))
    Else
        Timer1.Enabled = False

    End If
End Sub
```

You have to stop the timer when it is running.